# How to check an array before populating it

Tags: java, netbeans

Does anyone know how can I populate an array that checks if the positions are filled before filling them, and if they are already filled and if that array position is filled it increments to the next one.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your use case? Perhaps you'd be better off using a collection object, instead of an array?

Comment: How about actually **trying** to do this? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If it's an int(/primitive) array: If all possible starting values are possible values you'll have to keep track of used indexes yourself. Otherwise, initialize unused indexes to 0 (default) or -1 or some other placeholder. Use similar logic for other primitives. Otherwise, check for null.

Answer (score 3):

Primitive array elements are never empty. For example in an int array all elements will be initialized to 0.

So if you want to check for filled or not, initialize the array elements to a value which it is not going to take. say -1. Then each time you make an entry check for -1. The dummy value initialization is necessary as you can not check for 0, because 0 can be a valid data as well

// Initialization part

```
int [] arr= new int [17]; 
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
   arr[i]= -1;   
}
```

Hope you will do the checking part yourself

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming (possibly incorrectly) that you either a) want a method that inserts object into the first available (i.e. not null) spot in the array at or past the argument integer or b) want to insert repeatedly into the array using the method in a)

the method in a) would basically be as follows

```
public <Type> void myInsertMethod(Type[] array,Type item,int position)
{
while (array[pos]!=null)
    {pos++;}
array[pos]=item;
}
```

if you want to do this repeatedly on the same array, just call the method repeatedly, with different positions and items.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the position you are going to fill it's not null, or empty, or at least the stored value it's different to the one you are going to put

```
if(array.get(index) != "" && array.get(index) != null) && array.get(index) != newObject){
array.add(newObject);
}
```

Then, depending on the stored value type, you can ddo some more checks, for example in the cas e of the int, as RookieB says, you can check if the object is different to 0

Hope it helps

Comment: I did not say to check for if the element is different from 0, as 0 can also be a valid data

Comment: But at first, elements are set to 0, so is away to check if this value it is the initial value